# Why does Window.Open in classic asp work but not in asp.net?

Tags: asp.net, asp-classic, popup

I am using a window.open() to redirect to a new window that has no address bar and no menus.  Just a basic window.

This works currently in classic asp with setting toolbar=no, menubar=no but when it is used in the asp.net version of the site IE will open it with the toolbar and menus.

Is their a setting I need to set for my asp.net version?

```
dim lnk
lnk = "../../../default.aspx?id=" & strOrderNumber
dim onclick 
onclick = "window.open(this.href,'','toolbar=no,location=no,status=no,menubar=no,scrollbars=no,resizable=no,width=400,height=400');"
Response.Write "&nbsp;<a href='" & lnk & "' onclick='" & onclick & "'   style=""color: blue; text-decoration: underline;"" target='_blank' >Click Link</a>"
```

I do not think it is the code because currently on the classic asp version it works.  When used on .Net version it does not work.  Is ISS doing something?

Comment: post your code what u have tried

Comment: I added the code but the code is not the issue.  it works in classic asp site but when used in .net the menubar is showing.  That is why I asked if ISS is doing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

instead of doing a response.write to output the code I setup a java function and then just called it from the anchor tag.  Works great!